# Compute $\frac{d^n}{dx^n} \exp(a \exp(-x))$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Is there a way of finding the following derivative for every $n$
\begin{align}
\frac{d^n}{dx^n}  \exp(a \exp(-x))
\end{align}
for some fixed $a>0$

Computing the first few expressions is easy. However, it gets complicated after a  while.

$$
\begin{array}
$n & \frac{d^n}{dx^n}  \exp(a \exp(-x))\\ \hline
1 & -a \exp(a e^{-x} -x)\\
2 & a(a + e^x) \exp(a e^{-x} -2x) \\
3 & (-a)(a^2 + 3 a e^x + e^{2x})\exp(a e^{-x} -3x) \\
4 & a(a^3 + 6 a^2 e^x + 7a e^{2x} + e^{3x})\exp(a e^{-x} -4x) \\
5 & (-a)(a^4 + 10 a^3 e^x + 25 a^2 e^{2x} + 15 a e^{3x} + e^{4x})\exp(a e^{-x} -5x)
\end{array}
$$

Comment: I see a few patterns here. Firstly, we have $$\frac{d^n}{d x^n} e^{a e^{-x}} = (-1)^{n} \cdot a \cdot \exp(a e^{-x} - nx) \cdot p(a),$$ where $p(a)$ is a polynomial in $a$ of degree $n - 1$ and the coefficients of $e^{x}$ are given by the triangular numbers, $\frac{n(n - 1)}{2} \cdot a^{n - 2}$. The coefficients of $e^{2x}$ are given by [this oeis.org sequence](https://oeis.org/search?q=0%2C0%2C1%2C7%2C25&sort=&language=english&go=Search).

Comment: @ViktorGlombik It seems that you were almost there.   We still have to figure out what the polynomial is?

Answer (score 5):

Look up the Bell polynomials, for
$$ \exp(a\,e^{-x}) = e^a\,\exp{(a(e^{-x}-1))} =\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{B_k(a)}{k!} (-x)^k$$

Answer (score 2):

It can be written as
$$ e^{a e^{-x}} P_n(a e^{-x})$$
where $P_n$ is a polynomial of degree $n$, such that $P_0(t) = 1$ and
$$P_{n+1}(t) = -t (P_n(t) + P_n'(t)) $$

EDIT:
$P_{n}(t) = (-1)^n T_n(t)$ where $T_n$ are the [Touchard (BellB) polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touchard_polynomials).  Thus
$$ P_n(t) = (-1)^n \sum_{k=0}^n \left\{{ n \atop k}\right\} t^k$$
where $\left\{{n \atop k }\right\}$ are the Stirling numbers of the second kind.

Comment: How did you get the recurrence formula?

Comment: Take derivative of $e^{a e^{-x}} P_n(a e^{-x})$ and simplify.

Comment: Can the polynomial be written in an explicit way?

Comment: One more question. Does the sum in the polynomial start at $k=0$ or $k=1$?

Comment: It should start at $k=0$ (I'll edit).  However, the only case where that matters is $n=0$: all the others have constant term $0$, as you see from the recurrence.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see an easy way to solve this. I would have tried logarithmic differentiation. For $ y := e^{a e^{-x}}, $ we have $$ \begin{eqnarray}
\ln y = a e^{-x} \quad & \Rightarrow & \quad \dfrac 1y \dfrac {dy}{dx} = -a e^{-x} \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \Rightarrow \quad \dfrac{dy}{dx} = -a y e^{-x} \\
\quad & \Rightarrow & \quad \dfrac 1y \left( \dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2} \right) - \dfrac1{y^2} \left( \dfrac {dy}{dx} \right)^2 = a e^{-x}  \Rightarrow \quad \dfrac{d^2 y}{dx^2} = \cdots \\
\quad & \vdots & \phantom0
\end{eqnarray} $$